# Change color of output for different stream in terminal

Tags: java, terminal, printing, ansi-escape

First to clarify i am not talking about changing color in some ide's attached terminal but the normal terminal.

Secondly My problem:

I have 2 outputstreams both printing to system.out and system.err but i want the system.err one to print in red but the code just takes a stream and calls print and it is too big to change individually all the lines so is there a way that all the outputs to System.err will be red and System.out will be normal

I tried adding ANSI RED escape code before the code segment for System.err but then out also prints red how can i do have only err as red output!

My code now:

```
public class Main {
    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\033[0m";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.print(ANSI_RED);        
        doSomePrinting(System.out, System.err); // This is some method which prints both to System.out and System.err
        System.err.print(ANSI_RESET);        
    }
}
```

But inside the do something method when i print to System.err it is red but System.out also becomes red!

How to solve this issue?

Note : Please do not suggest to print ANSI_RED and ANSI_RESET before and after everything i print to System.err i know thats a solution but there are a lost of prints thus it will be very difficult to do it and it will be my last option if there are no other possible ways!

Comment: You can replace the System.err with your own PrintStream with System.setErr(). In your own PrintStream you can append ANSI_RED and ANSI_RESET at the start and end of every line of output.

Comment: @Alex yeah i think i would override the print method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as suggested in the comments i made a class extending PrintStream and override `print and` println` methods.

My `PrintStream` class:

```
public class ErrorStreamPrinter extends PrintStream {

    public ErrorStreamPrinter(OutputStream out) {
        super(out, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(String s) {
        super.print(Constants.ANSI_RED);
        super.print(s);
        super.print(Constants.ANSI_RESET);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(String s) {
        super.print(Constants.ANSI_RED);
        super.print(s);
        super.println(Constants.ANSI_RESET);
    }
}
```

Comment: That can only work if you can guarantee that the `print` calls are flushed before any `println` (or other, related output method) is called.